# how to setup environment for avalanche's test network

Tags: go, blockchain, local-network, avalanche

I'm new to avalanche and have never used go before. I have been trying to deploy an Avalanche local test network according to the [documentation](https://docs.avax.network/quickstart/create-a-local-test-network) in my ubuntu20.04 but it's not very clear what should exactly be done about the GOPATH.
It is mentioned:

> avalanche-network-runner will be installed into $GOPATH/bin, please make sure that $GOPATH/bin is in your $PATH, otherwise, you may not be able to run commands below.

but its not specified what to set the PATH or GOPATH to.
also the documentation mentions:

> 

```
# replace execPath with the path to AvalancheGo on your machine
# e.g., ${HOME}/go/src/github.com/ava-labs/avalanchego/build/avalanchego
AVALANCHEGO_EXEC_PATH="${HOME}/go/src/github.com/ava-labs/avalanchego/build/avalanchego"
```

however the avalanchego project was never said to be cloned.

can someone please provide the specific steps needed to get the avalanche local test network up and working?
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you encountering any error or what exactly is the issue ? you can learn more about GOPATH with `go help gopath`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows:

From [here](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanchego/releases), download the binary file and give your file path for AVALANCHEGO_EXEC_PATH.
`export AVALANCHEGO_EXEC_PATH="PATH_TO_AVALANCHEGO_BINARY`"

**Steps:**

- Install the [Avalanche CLI](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanche-cli), [Avalanche Network Node Runner](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanche-network-runner)
- Download the Avalanche Bin File

  - Export its path with AVALANCHEGO_EXEC_PATH

    `export AVALANCHEGO_EXEC_PATH="PATH_TO_AVALANCHEGO_BINARY`"
- Then, follow instruction [here](https://docs.avax.network/subnets/network-runner).